# How can I block http request using javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, debugging, request, block

I have a webpage which sends some statistics to the server, I want to block the request using javascript. Is there away I can capture the request and block a particular request?

Comment: If it's using AJAX, you can monkeypatch `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: ... and / or [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Have you considered an ad blocker?

Comment: adblocker will block it on my pc only but i want the webpage to block it automatically using js

Comment: Ah, you want to actually put some script in the page to block it? If you can edit the page, why not just remove the code making the request?

Comment: the script is too long and its almost impossible to find the exact function which is accessing url, so i was just thinking to block it simply.